# Getting errors while using ts-loader and babel-loader to convert typescript -> es6 and then to es5

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Hi there is my source code:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A webpack starter for Angular",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.3",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.3",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy" ]
}
```

**webpack.base.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: [ 'babel-polyfill', './app/main.ts' ],

/*entry: {
    'polyfill': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './app/main.ts'    
  },*/

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
       //test: /\.ts$/,
       //loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
       test: /\.ts$/, 
       loaders: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
       exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }      
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**webpack.development.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config.js');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = webpackMerge( baseConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }  
});
```

**webpack.production.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config.js');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = webpackMerge( baseConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }  
});
```

after running webpack --progress command, get the bundle of errors:

```
ERROR in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ang_babel\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts                                                                                                                
(5538,14): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.                                                                                               

ERROR in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ang_babel\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts                                                                                                                
(5557,14): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type 'string', but here has type '"Math"'.                        

ERROR in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ang_babel\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts                                                                                                                
(5557,14): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.                                                                                               

ERROR in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ang_babel\typings\globals\core-js\index.d.ts                                                                                                                      
(3,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.                                                                                                                                        

ERROR in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ang_babel\typings\globals\core-js\index.d.ts                                                                                                                      
(127,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '[Symbol.unscopables]'.                                                                                                                              
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":                                                                                                                                                      
        + 1 hidden modules
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: Why you don't want to convert from TS to ES5?

Comment: First of all you have multiple errors and you don't expect us to give you one answer for all the errors, right? Try to investigate these by yourself, and for each error you don't manage to solve, post a question. Second, it looks like you have errors in some .d.ts files, so please share the problematic lines here.

Answer (score 0):

Well after long time research i found that core-js was breaking the application and was cause of error. I uninstalled core-js and problem has solved.

**UPDATE**

> Babel includes a polyfill that includes a custom regenerator runtime
>   and core-js.

this is why it happened. You don't need to include

```
"core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759"
```

into typings.json file when using babel.